# Как сделать всплывающие панели?

Tags: java, android

Есть кнопка, надо при её нажатии открыть панель до половины экрана, то есть нажал пользователь кнопку, и снизу до половины экрана поднялась белая панель и на ней тексты кнопки и тд. Как такое реализовать? Может есть готовые библиотеки?

Comment: Это BottomSheet

Comment: Спасибо!нашел все что мне нцжно)

Comment: Пожалуйста) Будет не лишним, если вы в ответе опишите всё что нашли - это может помочь будущим посетителям вопроса)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При помощи [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html)  и [BottomSheetBehavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior.html) , так же, если хочешь эффекты по умолчанию (типа затемнение фона за этой панелью и сокрытие этой панели по клику на другую область) рекомендую использовать [BottomSheetDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialog.html).

Comment: Спасибо очень полезно !

Comment: а как делать чтоб по ннажатию с ним вместе поднимался floating buttn ?нету у тебя для этого ссылки ?

Comment: я с floating button пока не работал, но она тоже через behavior делается, глянь на хабре, я там вроде статью видел как всё вместе связать на коардинаторе.

Comment: @Да уже сделал )